# How to place view anywhere on screen?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, android-layout

On Android, what's a way to be able to place a view, like a WebView, anywhere on screen? I'm providing an interface to users where they can create a WebView dynamically and place it anywhere they want with X-Y and Width-Height parameters.

FrameLayout doesn't work since it sticks everything at a corner. RelativeLayout I'm not sure of. AbsoluteLayout seems like the best bet, but it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer did the trick:

[Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading your views into [Pictures](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html) and using a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) to draw them dynamically onto a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPicture%28android.graphics.Picture,%20android.graphics.Rect%29).  This would avoid using deprecated stuff, but to be honest I can't really see how it's any better than using an AbsoluteLayout.  You would still have the problem of having to specify your position in pixel units, which is why I assume AbsoluteLayout has been deprecated.

Comment: Never mind, Lumis's method sounds much better, as margins can use dp!

Comment: Actually it is RelativeLayout that can be use like this.