# How to setup this layout in android?

Tags: android, layout

In Android I'm trying to get a layout looking like [this image](http://oi51.tinypic.com/fuw7tj.jpg) using xml.

[image]

What I've been trying to do is to separate the view vertical into two parts. One for the blue part and one for the white. For the blue part I use a shape as background to get the gradient and for the white part just a white background. It works good for the "Title" and "Some text" part. But as the image view should overlay both layouts it isn't working.

I can't figure out how to setup the xml layout to get it working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="title"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="some text here"
        />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="title"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course, you'll need to set the layout width, height, ... on those elements.

Comment: Great! That worked perfect when setting layout_width="fill_parent" and layout_height="wrap_content" for both TextViews. The only thing now is that the ImageView and the image inside is positioned in the top left corner I want it to be centered vertically, how is that possible?

Comment: Check the RelativeLayout documentation, you'll find all the properties you need. In particular, one is named something like layout_centerVertical

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll find the answer here: [set the absolute position of a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)