# Issue with custom views in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have multiple custom views rendered on my screen in `RelativeLayout` using `LayoutParams`. Now first time user touches on view it increase it's size, after that when user once again clicks on that view, that view should get disappear. Now the problem is *when a view gets disappeared other views on screen changes their size and location*. By debugging I found that this happens when I pass dynamic values as width and height in `LayoutParams`. If I go for static then all works good. But then I'm not able to increase the size of view. How can I solve this? I also tried changing `View.GONE` to `View.INVISIBLE` but that also doesn't help.

I create all views in code and place them on screen. In my xml I don not have any view entry. I do this because initial size of views should be random. So I create view and assign him initial size in `LayoutParams(width, height)` and then use `topMargin` and `leftMargin` to place them at various positions on screen. More details can be found here: [Custom object click issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545416/custom-object-click-issue-in-android)

Comment: some code snippet please so that this can be answered better.

Comment: @Deva code is too large to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess without seeing any code...  It sounds like you are using layout_weight, and if a view is removed, the other views with a layout_weight will expand to fill the now available space.

Comment: I'm not using `layout_weight`.