# Draw custom View on a specific x\y coordinates

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to create a custom View (that will be inflated from XML) which will be drawn at given x\y coordinates.
I know I can create a custom View which will implement `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`, but I want this View to be inflated from XML.

On `Canvas` I can only draw lines, rectangles and such.. But I want to inflate a whole XML layout..

How can I do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up using `RelativeLayout` as mentioned here:

[Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a FrameLayout as a main layout.

Inflate the layout you want.

Add it to the FrameLayout.

Then add padding / margin with LayoutParams.