# Adding edit text dynamically on click

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an android application that allows the user to add text to an image. I need to **dynamically add an EditText to the layout on click**. The edit text should be positioned wherever the user clicks on the screen. I have been able to overlay an EditText on an imageview is as follows. How do I position it based on where I click on the screen.

The XML code for the layout is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>

<com.infy.CirclesDrawingView
    android:id="@+id/aview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dip" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any alternatives are also welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditText input = new EditText(this);` inside the onClickListener();

Comment: Hi, how will this help .Should he remove it from the layout file then

Answer (score 0):

With the help of touch gestures, you will get the x and y coordinate and you can place your edit text on that coordinate.

You can refer this link:

[How to get the Touch position in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android)

and then refer this link:

[Draw custom View on a specific x\y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479820/draw-custom-view-on-a-specific-x-y-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use OnTouchListner to get the co-ordinate of image where it is clicked the get the 
the dynamic EditText and put it there

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            System.out.println("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
//get the dynamic edit text and add it here
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```