# How to set layout parameters in Relativelayout using java code

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have created a layout using RelativeLayout, but I need to change the top margin when orientation changed to landscape .

```
   @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

   // Checks the orientation of the screen
   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
      // labelLayoutParams.setMargins(0, -100, 0, 0);
       layout.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);

       Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

but i get following exception

```
 06-25 22:22:31.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8211): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

so please help how can set layout parameters specially top margin for relativelayout?
programaticaly

Comment: My suggestion is to add use LayoutParams with the Relativelayout prefix, like this RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT. Maybe the IDE uses the wrong import such as LinearLayout for LayoutParams.

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
labelLayoutParams.topMargin = 10;
layout.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way as per [Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    params.topMargin = 60;

    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: `FILL_PARENT` is now deprecated, please use `MATCH_PARENT`