# resizing the imageView makes it change its place

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a Relative layout with few images in it like this below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/increase"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/increase"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_8"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my java file i need to perform a small task.
When i click an image it's size should be increased.
I tried this and it was working and this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

View imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView i1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.image_1);
    ImageView i2 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.image_2);
             ImageView i3 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.image_8);
            i1.setOnClickListener(this);
    i2.setOnClickListener(this);
    i3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Log.v("clicked ", "clicked");
    imageView = arg0;
    Toast.makeText(this, "looking to resize the image ", 1).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked 2", 1).show();

    height = imageView.getHeight();
        width = imageView.getWidth();
    height += 50;
    width += 50;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height, width));

}   

}
```

But i am facing a problem.
when i click the image its position is changing.
Consider these screen shots ..

The below is the screen shot when the application is launched

[image]

and below is the screen shot when an image view is clicked.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me so that the image doesnt change its position 
I can use something like using a grid view (if possible. but even i am trying to put some drag option to it. So can anyone suggest me please)

**UPDATED CODE :**

the onclick method is updated as below :

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Log.v("clicked ", "clicked");
    imageView = arg0;
    Toast.makeText(this, "looking to resize the image ", 1).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked 2", 1).show();

    height = imageView.getHeight();
width = imageView.getWidth();
    height += 50;
    width += 50;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height, width);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.setMargins( 
                imageView.getLeft()-30,imageView.getTop()-30,imageView.getRight()+30,
               imageView.getBottom()+30);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create new layoutparams for a relative layout and only set the height and width.  Therefore, the image view will default to top left of the parent relative layout.  You also need to set the alignment and margin as you need.

Since you are using a relative layout, you need to create new RelativeLayout layoutParams:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I searched for the alignment attribute for the imageView. But i failed to find it. Can you suggest me a little bit more please

Comment: ok i will give it a try and will be back.
But one doubt i understood setmargins() use and what is the use of addRule?

Comment: addRule enables you to specify the "relativity" of child views in the parent, for example alignment and "toTheRightOf" etc.  When a relative layout is asked to draw itself, it first asks all of it's children in the heirarchy to report their size and where they would like to be positioned.  To do this, it passes down the rules which the layout uses to position it's children.  Remember that with a relative layout, you must provide rules to position anything at other than top left.  In general, margins are not a good way to do this but sometimes, you can't avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i udpated my code as you suggested .But again i am facing a problem .
The image View that is clicked is moving to other place when clicked and is again moving back when clicked again.
Please suggest me a little more.

Comment: Please read the documentation (I linked to it in my answer) and also note that I included addRule only to show you how to add the alignments.  You should change addRule, and use as many addRules as you need, to make the image view position itself as you need.

Comment: Could anyone help me further please.
I didnt find the solution for this one.

Comment: Unfortunately "I didnt find the solution" is not going to enable anyone to help, regardless of how thorough their technical knowledge is, or how much they may want to help.  You're going to have to learn to ask questions that are specific and provide enough information so we can help.  You may find this a useful, and short, read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: it should be params.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);

Comment: @samgak  Good spot!  Thanks.