# Margin in Relative Layout

Tags: android, margin, android-relativelayout

How to set margin in relative layout with code (not XML)?

I use this code but nothing happened:

```
RelativeLayout rlDetail = new RelativeLayout(context);
rlDetail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_round);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlDetailParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rlDetailParams.setMargins(35, 10, 35, 0);
rlDetail.setLayoutParams(rlDetailParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this answer [set the absolute position of a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295056/886001)

as mentioned in the link above you should use

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
params.leftMargin = needed_margin;
params.topMargin = needed_margin;

// add your textview like this
rl.addView(tv1, params);
```

Comment: how are you adding views to this layout?
follow the example on the link to add views..

Comment: RelativeLayout rlDetail = new RelativeLayout(context);
  rlDetail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_round);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlDetailParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  rlDetailParams.setMargins(35, 10, 35, 0);
  rlDetail.setLayoutParams(rlDetailParams);
   TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
   tv1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   tv1.setText("Test");
   rlDetail.addView(tv1);

Comment: try adding the views like mentioned in the example from the link.. check my updated answer

Comment: i want set margin for relaltivelayout not the textview

Comment: this way the parameter are set for the `RelativeLayout` rl and then used to add the `TextView`..