# how can i align components non-relative positions in android activity

Tags: android

I am new at android programming. I just want to learn how to drag and drop any component to anywhere. I found some articles and forum QAs but could not find the answer i need.

Iwould like to free alingment which is not relative or linear. just drag n drop anywere and no sibling item will be effected from another. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the AbsoluteLayout, however that class is deprecated due to scaling issues. There also exists the FrameLayout class however generally that is only for a single child.

Please visit [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android), as it asks the same question and you may find the answers suiting.

AbsoluteLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html
FrameLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Duplicate Thread: [Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)