# Custom View in Relative Layout overlapping other Custom Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view, android-relativelayout

i'm using a relative layout with a couple of custom views. 
Each custom view is a collored square, drawn on an own canvas. I want to add a clicklistener to each custom view. 
Now when adding all Views(with clicklistener) to the layout , only the last custom view added is clickable even when clicking beside the square. Perhaps the problem is that the canvas of this View is overlapping the other canvases. I can see that by setting the backround of each view black. --> only the last view is visible with black background.
how can i avoid that problem (without using ontouch and coordinate request)
how can i remove that transparent canvas which i am not using.

edit:

```
public class StorageView extends View {

Paint paintedStorage = new Paint(); 
int sizeX,sizeY,koordX,koordY;
Storage storage;

public StorageView(Context context, Storage storage, double ratio) {
    super(context);
    this.koordX = (int)(storage.getKoordX()*ratio);
    this.koordY = (int)(storage.getKoordY()*ratio);
    this.sizeX = (int)(storage.getSizeX()*ratio);
    this.sizeY = (int)(storage.getSizeY()*ratio);
    this.storage = storage;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(storage.getArticleList().isEmpty())
        paintedStorage.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    else
        paintedStorage.setColor(Color.CYAN);

    paintedStorage.setStrokeWidth(3);

    canvas.drawRect(koordX, koordY, koordX+sizeX, koordY+sizeY, paintedStorage);

}

public Storage getStorage(){
    return storage;
}
```

This in my Activity: (StorageView is my square or rectangle)

```
            for (int i = 0; i < storageList.size(); i++) {
            storageListView.add(new StorageView(context, storageList.get(i), ratio));
            //  storageListView.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                storageListView.get(i).setClickable(true);

                    storageListView.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {/*Do something (Toast)*/}});
                relativeKoordLayout.addView(storageListView.get(i));
            }
```

edit: i got it "[Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)"
worked out fine!

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: thanks for fast response. i shortened the code and added it. do you need some screenshots?

Comment: i think my aproach is a little bit wrong by adding a couple of canvases