# Android - Set ImageView's position sdk 10

Tags: android, view, position, imageview, setx

someone could tell me how to write this code → "ImageView1.setX(ImageView1.getX() - 1)" with sdk 10 (Android version 2.3.6 or below) because "setX" and "getX" is with sdk 11.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of the ImageView, I would use `View.getLocationInWindow()` and/or `View.getLocationOnScreen()`. Explore LayoutParams for setting the position of the ImageView. See this: [Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)

Comment: Ok, I will see View.getLocationOnScreen().

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android work but is long when I have 10 or more ImageView to move.

I have already test these:

"ImageView1.setLeft(ImageView1.getLeft() - 1);"

"ImageView1.layout(ImageView1.getLeft() - 1, 10, -50, 0);"

but don't work.

Comment: I think setLeft() and getLeft() are not available in API10 either.

Answer (score 0):

Finely, [Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android) is only reduce the picture not the view, I can't scroll an ImageView with this.