# Display an image in Android (preferably with ImageView

Tags: android

I am trying to display a 54x52 PNG file. I've looked all over the web and all of the tutorials have OnClickListener() or something else in them. [This](http://oi58.tinypic.com/20p9348.jpg) is the image I have in mind. I want this image to be displayed on the bottom-right corner of the screen. I don't want the app to do anything if the image is clicked on, and I want this image to be displayed the entire time the app is on-screen. How would I do this? What would my /res/layout/main.xml look like, as well as the actual source code itself?

Here is my /res/layout/main.xml so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp">
    <Button android:id="@+id/open" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="OpenClicked" android:text="Open MIDI file..." />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/position" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:max="0" android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="10dp">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Tempo (in BPM)" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <SeekBar android:id="@+id/tempo" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:max="20" android:progress="10" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/bpm" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/effects" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="EffectsClicked" android:text="Reverb &amp;&#10;Chorus" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:checked="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Lyrics" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lyrics" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:minLines="3" android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Soundfont (.SF2 file)" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/fontinfo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/openfont" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="OpenFontClicked" android:text="Browse..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my main .java file:

```
package com.theblackmidimasta.bassmidiplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;

import com.un4seen.bass.BASS;
import com.un4seen.bass.BASSMIDI;

public class MIDIPlayer extends Activity {
int chan;           // channel handle
int font;           // soundfont
int miditempo;      // MIDI file tempo
float temposcale=1; // tempo adjustment
int updatefont;
String lyrics;      // lyrics buffer

ImageView image;

Handler handler=new Handler();
File filepath;
String[] filelist;

class RunnableParam implements Runnable {
    Object param;
    RunnableParam(Object p) { param=p; }
    public void run() {}
}

// display error messages
void Error(String es) {
    // get error code in current thread for display in UI thread
    String s=String.format("%s", es, BASS.BASS_ErrorGetCode());
    runOnUiThread(new RunnableParam(s) {
        public void run() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MIDIPlayer.this)
                .setMessage((String)param)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .show();
        }
    });
}

BASS.SYNCPROC LyricSync=new BASS.SYNCPROC() {
    public void SYNCPROC(int handle, int channel, int data, Object user) {
        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK mark=new BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK();
        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetMark(channel, (Integer)user, data, mark); // get the lyric/text
        if (mark.text.charAt(0)=='@') return; // skip info
        if (mark.text.charAt(0)=='\\') // clear display
            lyrics+="\n\n"+mark.text.substring(1);
        else if (mark.text.charAt(0)=='/') // new line
            lyrics+="\n"+mark.text.substring(1);
        else
            lyrics+=mark.text;
        int lines, nlpos=0;
        for (lines=1; (nlpos=lyrics.indexOf('\n', nlpos))>=0; lines++, nlpos++) ; // count lines
        if (lines>3) { // remove old lines so that new lines fit in display...
            nlpos=0;
            do {
                nlpos=lyrics.indexOf('\n', nlpos)+1;
            } while (--lines>3);
            lyrics=lyrics.substring(nlpos);
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyrics)).setText(lyrics);
            }
        });
    }
};

BASS.SYNCPROC EndSync=new BASS.SYNCPROC() {
    public void SYNCPROC(int handle, int channel, int data, Object user) {
        lyrics=""; // clear lyrics
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyrics)).setText("");
            }
        });
    }
};

void SetTempo(boolean reset)
{
    if (reset) miditempo=BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetEvent(chan, 0, BASSMIDI.MIDI_EVENT_TEMPO); // get the file's tempo
    BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamEvent(chan, 0, BASSMIDI.MIDI_EVENT_TEMPO, (int)(miditempo*temposcale)); // set tempo
}

BASS.SYNCPROC TempoSync=new BASS.SYNCPROC() {
    public void SYNCPROC(int handle, int channel, int data, Object user) {
        SetTempo(true); // override the tempo
    }
};

// look for a marker (eg. loop points)
boolean FindMarker(int handle, String text, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK mark)
{
    for (int a=0; BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetMark(handle, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_MARKER, a, mark); a++) {
        if (mark.text.equals(text)) return true; // found it
    }
    return false;
}

BASS.SYNCPROC LoopSync=new BASS.SYNCPROC() {
    public void SYNCPROC(int handle, int channel, int data, Object user) {
        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK mark=new BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK();
        if (FindMarker(channel, "loopstart", mark)) // found a loop start point
            BASS.BASS_ChannelSetPosition(channel, mark.pos, BASS.BASS_POS_BYTE|BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_DECAYSEEK); // rewind to it (and let old notes decay)
        else
            BASS.BASS_ChannelSetPosition(channel, 0, BASS.BASS_POS_BYTE|BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_DECAYSEEK); // else rewind to the beginning instead
    }
};

public void OpenClicked(View v) {
    String[] list=filepath.list();
    if (list==null) list=new String[0];
    if (!filepath.getPath().equals("/")) {
        filelist=new String[list.length+1];
        filelist[0]="..";
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, filelist, 1, list.length);
    } else
        filelist=list;
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Coose a MIDI file to play")
        .setItems(filelist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                File sel;
                if (filelist[which].equals("..")) sel=filepath.getParentFile();
                else sel=new File(filepath, filelist[which]);
                if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                    filepath=sel;
                    OpenClicked(null);
                } else {
                    String file=sel.getPath();
                    BASS.BASS_StreamFree(chan); // free old stream before opening new
                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyrics)).setText(""); // clear lyrics display
                    if ((chan=BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamCreateFile(file, 0, 0, BASS.BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP|(((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.effects)).isChecked()?0:BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_NOFX), 1))==0) {
                        // it ain't a MIDI
                        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.open)).setText("Open MIDI file...");
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("");
                        ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.position)).setMax(0);
                        Error("Unsupported File Format! (it ain't a MIDI)");
                        return;
                    }
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.open)).setText(file);
                    // set the title (track name of first track)
                    BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK mark=new BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK();
                    if (BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetMark(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_TRACK, 0, mark) && mark.track==0)
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(mark.text);
                    else
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("");
                    // update pos scroller range (using tick length)
                    ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.position)).setMax((int)BASS.BASS_ChannelGetLength(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_POS_MIDI_TICK)/120);
                    // set looping syncs
                    if (FindMarker(chan, "loopend", mark)) // found a loop end point
                        BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan, BASS.BASS_SYNC_POS|BASS.BASS_SYNC_MIXTIME, mark.pos, LoopSync, 0); // set a sync there
                    BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan, BASS.BASS_SYNC_END|BASS.BASS_SYNC_MIXTIME, 0, LoopSync, 0); // set one at the end too (eg. in case of seeking past the loop point)
                    // clear lyrics buffer and set lyrics syncs
                    lyrics="";
                    if (BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetMark(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_LYRIC, 0, mark)) // got lyrics
                        BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_SYNC_MIDI_MARK, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_LYRIC, LyricSync, (Integer)BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_LYRIC);
                    else if (BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetMark(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_TEXT, 20, mark)) // got text instead (over 20 of them)
                        BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_SYNC_MIDI_MARK, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_TEXT, LyricSync, (Integer)BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_MARK_TEXT);
                    BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan, BASS.BASS_SYNC_END, 0, EndSync,0);
                    // override the initial tempo, and set a sync to override tempo events and another to override after seeking
                    SetTempo(true);
                    BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_SYNC_MIDI_EVENT|BASS.BASS_SYNC_MIXTIME, BASSMIDI.MIDI_EVENT_TEMPO, TempoSync, 0);
                    BASS.BASS_ChannelSetSync(chan,BASS.BASS_SYNC_SETPOS|BASS.BASS_SYNC_MIXTIME, 0, TempoSync, 0);
                    // get default soundfont in case of matching soundfont being used
                    BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FONT[] sf=new BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FONT[1];
                    if (BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamGetFonts(chan, sf, 1)>0)
                        font=sf[0].font;
                    // limit CPU usage to 70% and start playing
                    BASS.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_ATTRIB_MIDI_CPU, 70);
                    BASS.BASS_ChannelPlay(chan, false);
                }
            }
        })
        .show();
}

public void OpenFontClicked(View v) {
    String[] list=filepath.list();
    if (list==null) list=new String[0];
    if (!filepath.getPath().equals("/")) {
        filelist=new String[list.length+1];
        filelist[0]="..";
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, filelist, 1, list.length);
    } else
        filelist=list;
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Choose a soundfont to use")
        .setItems(filelist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                File sel;
                if (filelist[which].equals("..")) sel=filepath.getParentFile();
                else sel=new File(filepath, filelist[which]);
                if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                    filepath=sel;
                    OpenFontClicked(null);
                } else {
                    String file=sel.getPath();
                    int newfont=BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FontInit(file, 0);
                    if (newfont==0) {
                        Error("Unsupported File Format! (it ain't a SoundFont)");
                    } else {
                        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FONT[] sf={new BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FONT()};
                        sf[0].font=newfont;
                        sf[0].preset=-1; // use all presets
                        sf[0].bank=0; // use default bank(s)
                        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamSetFonts(0, sf, 1); // set default soundfont
                        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_StreamSetFonts(chan, sf, 1); // set for current stream too
                        BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FontFree(font); // free old soundfont
                        font=newfont;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .show();
}

public void EffectsClicked(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
        BASS.BASS_ChannelFlags(chan, 0, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_NOFX); // enable FX
    else
        BASS.BASS_ChannelFlags(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_NOFX, BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_NOFX); // disable FX
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    filepath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // initialize default output device
    if (!BASS.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0)) {
        Error("Can't initialize audio device!");
        return;
    }

    // load optional plugins for packed soundfonts
    String libpath=getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir;
    BASS.BASS_PluginLoad(libpath+"/libbassflac.so", 0);
    BASS.BASS_PluginLoad(libpath+"/libbasswv.so", 0);

    ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.position)).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                BASS.BASS_ChannelSetPosition(chan, progress*120, BASSMIDI.BASS_POS_MIDI_TICK); // set the position
                // clear lyrics
                lyrics="";
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyrics)).setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.tempo)).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                temposcale=1/((10+progress)/20.f); // up to +/- 50% bpm
                SetTempo(false); // apply the tempo adjustment
            }
        }
    });

    // timer to update the display
    Runnable timer=new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            if (chan!=0) {
                ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.position)).setProgress((int)BASS.BASS_ChannelGetPosition(chan, BASSMIDI.BASS_POS_MIDI_TICK)/120); // update position
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.bpm)).setText(String.format("%.1f", 60000000/(miditempo*temposcale))); // update bpm
            }
            if ((++updatefont&1)==1) { // only updating font info once a second
                String text="None";
                BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FONTINFO i=new BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FONTINFO();
                if (BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FontGetInfo(font, i))
                    text=String.format("%s", i.name, i.samload, i.samsize);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.fontinfo)).setText(text);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(timer, 500);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // free the output device and all plugins and the soundfont
    BASS.BASS_Free();
    BASS.BASS_PluginFree(0);
    BASSMIDI.BASS_MIDI_FontFree(font);

    super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have got so far and be more precise on the issue you encounter.

Comment: Add ImageView in the layout and don't bind any event. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view

Comment: So would i have to edit my .java file? or scince the image does nothing, would I just have to edit my /res/layout/main.xml file?