# How to place a picture at some specific position in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to place a picture at some user input specific pixels on the screen in android. if a user taps at a certain point than an image should be pasted on that point. my main concern is not getting the pixels but putting an image within that set of pixels (I am having a set of pixels within that i have to re-scale the image and than place it at that position )

Comment: did you try to use the onTouchListener and get the coordinates from the MotionEvent object? 

       view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
//                motionEvent.getX()  
//                motionEvent.getY()
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: as told by Ran hfirst find the touch coordinates on screen by using `view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { // motionEvent.getX() // motionEvent.getY() return false; } });`

Comment: my main concern is not getting the pixels but putting an image within that set of pixels (I am having a set of pixels within that i have to re-scale the image and than place it at that position )

Comment: then follow the link given in my below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as told by Ran hassid first find the touch coordinates on screen by using

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
 motionEvent.getX()
 motionEvent.getY()
 return false; } });
```

and then follow this answer to show image at obtained cordinates by above code-
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view)

Comment: great i will try this. Thank you