# android.widget.AbsoluteLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android

I added a progressbar in my custom webview, but when I scroll the view, it caused this error 
[image: Error info:]

This is my onScrollChanged method:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int left, int top, int oldLeft, int oldTop) {
        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams)  progressbar.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.leftMargin = left;
        layoutParams.topMargin = top;
        progressbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        super.onScrollChanged(left, top, oldLeft, oldTop);
    }
```

This is my imports:

```
    import com.fccs.library.R; 
import com.fccs.library.callback.SingleButtonCallBack; 
import com.fccs.library.notice.DialogUtils; 
import com.tencent.smtt.export.external.interfaces.JsResult; 
import com.tencent.smtt.sdk.WebSettings; 
import com.tencent.smtt.sdk.WebView; 
import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import android.view.KeyEvent; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
```

Comment: OK，thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing **LayoutParams** with **FrameLayout.LayoutParams** and check for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Change **LayoutParams**  to **AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams**

Comment: Yes, I changed the LayoutParams to AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams, it worked. But, the AbsoluteLayout is deprecation

Comment: @Ethen this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view

Answer (score 0):

Every Layout provides its own LayoutParams class -- seems you're using the wrong one in the first line of the method. Check your import and fix it.