# View positioning using setX and setY

Tags: android, android-framelayout

i've encountered a strange problem with view positioning..

the code i have is roughly like so:

```
 FrameLayout frame = callback.getFrame();
CustomView v = new CustomView(getActivity());
frame.addView(v);
v.setX(someX);
v.setY(someY);
//go on and do other stuff..
```

whereas the callback is the mainActivity that implements an interface where
i've put the method getFrame(), which returns the FrameLayout declared in the main layout file.

i've also tried using a different approach as mentioned here [Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view)

but still, stangely enough on the emulator the view does get shown in the proper place, but on an actual device it does not,
i mean not shown, or shown at the edge of the FrameLayout.

i've tested it with my nexus 5 phone, (LG, API 23)
also on a SAMSUNG 7J (API 25)
with the same result, and as i mentioned, when i test it on the emulator with 
the same API level, things work as intended.
the only "Solution" i came up with was to animate() the view which does put it
where i wanted, but it just does not feel right.

has anyone encountered this? what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after some trial and error runs, i came to a solution for this,
it seems that i needed to add LayoutParams to the CustomView

```
v.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY));
```

where the Gravity.NO_GRAVITY was the thing that made the difference, now the view is added to the correct location, using simple setX and setY methods..