# creating buttons positioned randomly, without exceeding the screen size

Tags: java, android, button, random

I'm trying to create an Activity that contains 10 buttons that are generated programmatically and are positioned in random places on the screen but without exceed the screen size.

I tried doing so but most of the buttons exceeded from the screen size (I couldn't see it).

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    for(int x = 0;x<10;x++) {

        Button btn = new Button(this);

        int Xpoistion = rnd.nextInt(width - 100) + 100;
        int Yposition = rnd.nextInt(height - 100) + 100;

        btn.setX(Xpoistion);
        btn.setY(Yposition);

        btn.setText(x +")"+width + "," + height + " | " + Xpoistion + "," + Yposition);

        linearLayout.addView(btn);

    }
```

So i'm trying to create the "limits of the screen" from height and width but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I played with Xposition and Yposition a lot but nothing seems to work for me.

Thank for very much for your help.

Comment: Why are you adding 100 to the random values? this will give you a left/top position of the buttons between 100 and displayWidth resp. 100 and displayHeight. And the button placed there will go off screen to right/bottom.

Comment: @Ridcully I just played with it, I tried a lot of options, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `RelativeLayout` as said already. But your logic is a bit flawed, you should set variables to garantee your buttons don't go of screen. I added a bit of code to yours already

```
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int buttonWidth = 150;
    int buttonHeigh = 40;
    int max_x_val = width - buttonWidth;
    int max_y_val = heigth - buttonHeigh; // Edited here

    for(int x = 0;x<10;x++) {

        Button btn = new Button(this);

        int Xpoistion = rnd.nextInt(max_x_val - buttonWidth) + buttonWidth;
        int Yposition = rnd.nextInt(max_y_val - buttonHeigh) + buttonHeigh;

        btn.setX(Xpoistion);
        btn.setY(Yposition);
        btn.setWidth(buttonWidth);
        btn.setHeight(buttonHeigh);
        btn.setText(x +")"+width + "," + height + " | " + Xpoistion + "," + Yposition);

        relativeLayout.addView(btn);
        Log.d("Debug","Xpos =" + Xpoistion);
        Log.d("Debug","Ypos =" + Yposition);
    }
```

This still is not the solution because the buttons might end up overlapped

**Last edit**

There are still some buttons that get a bit cut.This happens because we have the whole dimensions of the screen, and what we needed was the dimensions of only our `Relative Layout` .. That blue bar on top is also being included in the measure when it shouldn't. But this error is a bit more tricky to fix but not impossible, just google a bit and you will find enough help

**EDIT**: My initial thought was that `btn.setX()` and `setY()` would center the `Button` on those pixels, but no it marks the start of the button in those same pixels, so I had to change the randomize function to simply:

```
int Xposition = rnd.nextInt(width - buttonWidth);
int Yposition = rnd.nextInt(height - buttonHeight);
```

Next, to work around overlapping I wrote the following sample

```
// Create dummy class for holding coordinates
public class ButtonCordinates{

 public int x;
 public int y;

 public ButtonCordinates(int x, int y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 }
}

//In MainActivity class create a array for holding coordinates
ButtonCoordinates [] buttonsCoordinates = new ButtonCoordinates [10];    

int x = 0;
while(x < 10) {

  int Xposition = rnd.nextInt(width - buttonWidth);
  int Yposition = rnd.nextInt(height - buttonHeight);

  ButtonCoordinates buttonCoords = new ButtonCoordinates (Xposition,Yposition);

  if(!coordinatesFree(buttonCoords,buttonHeight,buttonWidth)){
    // Get another chance
    continue;
  }

  Button btn = new Button(this);
  btn.setX(Xposition);
  btn.setY(Yposition);

  btn.setWidth(buttonWidth);
  btn.setHeight(buttonHeight);
  btn.setText(Xposition+";"+Yposition);

  buttonsCoordinatesArray[x++] = buttonCoords;

  linearLayout.addView(btn);
  Log.d("Debug","Xpos =" + Xposition);
  Log.d("Debug","Ypos =" + Yposition);
}

// Method that prevents overlapping
private boolean coordinatesFree(ButtonCoordinates newButton, int buttonHeight, int buttonWidth){

     for(ButtonCoordinates existingButton : buttonsCoordinatesArray){
        if(existingButton == null){
            // First button ever
            return true;
        }

        boolean f1 = existingButton.x + buttonWidth <= newButton.x;
        boolean f2 = existingButton.y + buttonHeight <= newButton.y;
        boolean f3 = existingButton.x - buttonWidth >= newButton.x;
        boolean f4 = existingButton.y - buttonHeight >= newButton.y;

        if(!f1 && !f2 && !f3 && !f4){
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will figure the overlapped thing out now! You are awesome :)

Comment: @user2561521 max_y_val variable updated. I was using `width` on her. Please update in yours aswell

Comment: Where does buttonsCoordinatesArray comes from?

Comment: @user2561521 Just use it as a field in `MainActivity`

Comment: @user2561521 Check my last edit. It's important for you to fix it eventually and it shouldn't take much of your time

Comment: You are a true king.

Comment: @user2561521 It has been fun! GL

Comment: Hi, I tried your sample for several times and there are still some overlapping, can you please help me figure it out?
I followed your instructions step by step and everything is working except for the overlapping in two / three buttons everytime I run the application.

Comment: I believe its about the styling of the button. Show me a picture where it happens and with the logs of the distances between them. I ll assume that the width and height of the button are still 150 and 40 respectively.

Comment: You can also debug the method that deals with the overlapping and check where is it failing.

Comment: Ok, so this is the picture where it happens: https://imgur.com/a/FStem



In the part where I create each button I give each button (as you wrote in the sample code) a width and height attribute from the vars (150 x 40).
And that is why I can't understand why there are still overlapping left..

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @user2561521 That's why I said there must be something wrong with the button styling, cause the pixel difference is 913 - 829 = **84** . There's more than enough room for not overlapping ( about 4 pixels ), because it's 40 height for 1st button + 40 for the 2nd button + 4 of distance between them. I can't really explain what's happening

Comment: @user2561521 As a test, make 2 buttons with 80 pixel difference in Y coordinate, print me the results also. Give them different colors aswell

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout to place your buttons with absolute values.

Edit: I just looked for a reference, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295056/9093967).

Comment: Thanks! I will look it out!